# How to select xml nodes in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

i have a simple code that should alert the text in the node "Desc" from the last element "Term" , but i get no alert:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dictionary.xml", true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDictionary = xmlhttp.responseXML;

var Decnod=xmlDictionary.evaluate("Terms/Term[last()]/Key/Desc[text()]", xmlDictionary, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

alert(Decnod);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What does your `Dictionary.xml` file look like?

Comment: Try running Chrome with: " C:\ ... \Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files"

Answer (score 0):

solved it! changed 
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dictionary.xml", true);
to 
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Dictionary.xml", false);